Excel formula =LEFT(D2,11)" doesn't work as expected
I used =LEFT(D2,11) to retrieve the date from a date & time cell, and instead of a date I got a number.
The content of the cell is 9/1/2017  12:02:01 AM, but the returned value was 42979.00140. What should I do to make it work properly?
I tried changing the formatting of the cells and it made no difference.

Dates are doubles formatted to look like a date.  The Integer is the number of days since Dec 31st 1899. With the decimal as the part of the day. The number is then formatted to look like a date and/or time. But the underlying value is a double and not a date.
The Left is returning the left 11 characters of a 15 significant digit number 42979.001400463, the . counts as 1 character.
If you want just the date do something like:
=INT(D2)

And format it mm/dd/yyyy

Anyway, can you explain why is 42979.00140 returned?

@rotabor dates in Excel are stored as doubles.  The Integer is the number of days since Dec 31st 1899.  With the decimal as the part of the day.  The number is then formatted to look like a date and/or time.  But the underlying value is a double and not a date. And the Left is returning the left 11 characters of a 15 significant digit number, the . counts as 1 character.

@MayukhBhattacharya Check and think on it.

@rotabor maybe I am answering the wrong question.  What do you think it should have returned?

The question is "Does =LEFT(D2,11) work as expected?"

@MayukhBhattacharya Where is =LEFT(D2,11)?

@MayukhBhattacharya Nevertheless, OP applied =LEFT(D2,11), got 42979.00140 and asked why?

"The Left is returning the left 11 characters" of the text representation of 42979.001400463 due to automatic conversion its argument to text.

@rotabor is the question about retrieving dates or not understanding how LEFT behaves?

@P.b It depends on how to look at it. I guess OP needs both.

What is magic 42979.00140 repeats through questions?

@P.b What do you think about magic 42979.00140 (2017-09-01 to be precise) which repeats through questions? (Links under "This question already has answers here".)

@Rotabor That is more than coincidental, considering it's 2024. Maybe it's a question in a training somewhere?
